# Reformat date through regex expressions with gsub in Awk

Tags: date, awk, gsub

I want to reformat date from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD with gsub in Awk.

I have used the command:

```
awk '{gsub(/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/, "([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})", $4)}1' OFS='       ' example.tsv > example_date.tsv
```

on input file:

```
No  Name    LastName    Date    
1   Jane    Doe         24/05/1978  
2   James   Cook        04/04/1974  
3   Jack    Smith       24/05/1978
4   John    Beck        20/10/1980
```

The output file `example_date.tsv` is exactly same as the input file. I was wondering what could be changed here.

Comment: Your year parts contain 2 digits, but in your pattern, you have `[0-9]{4}`. Besides, you did not use backreferences in the replacement, you just put the regex back there, and anyway, they are not supported by `awk` `sub`. You'd need GNU awk `gensub`.

Comment: So, something like `awk '{$4=gensub(/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})/, "\\3-\\2-\\1", "g", $4)}1' file`

Comment: how do you decide between 2014 and 1914 for YY=14 ?

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew! The {4} part was a mistake while writing a code here in question, in terminal I used {2}, what I was missing was gensub instead of gsub. I haven't heard about it until now, it's amazing! Thank you so much once again, super helpful.

Comment: @jhnc this is the dummy file, in the real file years are in the "YYYY" format (that's why I made a mistake while typing a code above with {4} instead of {2}).

Comment: if your 'real' file contains years in `YYYY` format then your sample files should also contain years in `YYYY` format; generally speaking, your sample data should 'look like' your real data otherwise you run the risk of *a)* confusing us and/or *b)* receiving an answer that does not work with your actual data; please update the question with sample data that's representative of your real data; also, update the question to show the expected output

Comment: does your data file contain the header record `No  Name    LastName    Date `? if not, please remove from your sample data; does the `.tsv` file extension mean that you wish to use a tab (`\t`) as the input/output field delimiter? if 'no', what are the input/output field delimiters?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples Only, please try following in GNU `awk`.

- Setting `RS`(record separator) as `[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+(\\s+|$)` for all the lines to get the desired values to be edited here as per question.
- Then checking if value of `RT` is NOT NULL using `match` function to get the values of RT in capturing groups to change their Order later on as per requirement by OP.

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+(\\s+|$)' '
RT && sub(/\n+$/,"",RT){
  match(RT,/^([[:space:]]+)([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([0-9]+)(.*)$/,arr)
  print $0 arr[1] arr[4] "/" arr[3] "/" arr[2] arr[5]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- OP's real data contains dates in `YYYY` format (per comment from OP)
- input/ouput field delimiters are tabs (`\t`)

Setup:

```
$ cat example.tsv
No      Name    LastName        Date
1       Jane    Doe     24/05/1978
2       James   Cook    04/04/1974
3       Jack    Smith   24/05/1978
4       John    Beck    20/10/1980
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR>1  { split($4,a,"/")                       # split 4th field on "/" delimiter and place in array a[]
        $4 = a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1]           # rebuild 4th field in YYYY-MM-DD format
      }
1
' example.tsv
```

This generates:

```
No      Name    LastName        Date
1       Jane    Doe     1978-05-24
2       James   Cook    1974-04-04
3       Jack    Smith   1978-05-24
4       John    Beck    1980-10-20
```

---

Assumptions:

- input field delimiter is white space (could be spaces, tabs, or a mix); OP's sample data appears as fixed width
- OP's `gsub()` regex only matches on the 4th column

Setup:

```
$ cat example.tsv
No    Name      LastName    Date
1     Jane      Doe         24/05/1978
2     James     Cook        04/04/1974
3     Jack      Smith       24/05/1978
4     John      Beck        20/10/1980
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ split($4,a,"/")
  gsub(/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/,a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1])
}
1
' example.tsv
```

This generates:

```
No    Name      LastName    Date
1     Jane      Doe         1978-05-24
2     James     Cook        1974-04-04
3     Jack      Smith       1978-05-24
4     John      Beck        1980-10-20
```